# How to record screen after permission is granted

Tags: java, android, screen-recording

When app is displayed permission window is being displayed  in order to recording screen and when certain button is pressed, recording stops and it is available to be seen. After that screen should automatically be recorded again without asking for permission again, however permission window keeps asking for permission although permission was just granted. This is my code.

```
private void screenRecordingRequestCodeRequest() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, SCREEN_RECORDING_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode == SCREEN_RECORDING_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Intent intent = ScreenRecordingService.newIntent(this, resultCode, data);
            boolean isServiceRunning = Utils.isServiceRunning(this, ScreenRecordingService.class);
            boolean isFinishCode = (resultCode == 0);
            if ((isServiceRunning && isFinishCode) || (!isServiceRunning && !isFinishCode)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(intent);
                } else {
                    startService(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finish();
}
```